# Strange looking mushroom found in a dead tree

Tags: species-identification, mycology, mushroom

I'm trying to identify this mushroom my sister found at her campus' lawn. It is brown, looks somewhat like a turtle or a brain and is growing inside of a dead tree trunk. Geographically the campus is in Haifa, Israel in case that helps. Any ideas?

Images:

[image: turtle mushroom from the side]
[image: to get a sense of scale]
[image: looks like a brain?]

Comment: Is it too dark to be [Boletus subtomentosus](http://mushroomobserver.org/4228?q=1bswm) ? (another pic [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/steve_chilton/2784257095/))

Comment: Have you tried [mycokey](http://www.mycokey.com/newMycoKeySite/MycoKeyIdentQuick.html)? Looks like there are a lot of factors that can't be seen in that picture which might be important.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Species: **California Fungi** - *Gymnopilus luteofolius*

[image]

Source:

http://www.mykoweb.com/CAF/species/Gymnopilus_luteofolius.html

http://mushroomobserver.org/174362?q=28kZM

[image]